# jquery function argument neglecting zeros

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Here I have a mvcjqgrid from which i am having an link button as below

```
mvcJqGrid.demo.buttonize = function (cellvalue, options, rowobject) {   
    return <a onclick="return mvcJqGrid.demo.showIdproofmodal('+options.rowId+')"><div class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" style="display:inline-block"></div></a>
}
```

And here I have the function for the link button.

```
mvcJqGrid.demo.showIdproofmodal = function (id){
    $("#NoteDialog").load("/UserAccount/UploadIdProof/" + id, function () 
    {alert(id); 
    $("#NoteDialog").dialog('open'); });
                return false;
    }
```

When the function **`mvcJqGrid.demo.showIdproofmodal(00038748492234)`** passes a value like above I receive the no as *`38748492234`* in my actual function, which causes me some functional error, I need to get the exact value in the argument type. Help me.

Comment: what is the datatype of `options.rowId` ? Looks like it is numeric causing loss of leading zero's.

Comment: you need to convert it to a string, try something like id+""

Comment: Mates options.rowId is a String that i have used in mvcjqgrid. Actually when i print it as options.rowId i get it right. but when it is passed on to the function. It gets truncated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
mvcJqGrid.demo.buttonize = function (cellvalue, options, rowobject) {   
    return "<a onclick=\"return mvcJqGrid.demo.showIdproofmodal('"+options.rowId+"')\"><div class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil' style='display:inline-block'></div></a>"
}
```

**Update:**

1. Here you have called the function as
   `showIdproofmodal(00038748492234)`. In this case javascript will
   consider the parameter as a number.
2. When it is modified to `showIdproofmodal('00038748492234')`,
   javascript engine will consider it a string variable.

Comment: That works fine. Thanks. Can you just explain y it occurred and what have you done.

Answer (score 0):

If the data type is a number, then there is no difference between `00038748492234` and `38748492234`.

The zeroes will be preserved if you pass the data as a string.

You don't show us what `options.rowId` is or how it's set - we'd have to see that code to understand what data types are being used there and what to advise for making sure it's a string.